Attributes in Woocommerce not visable
I have added more than 6000 products via bulk import including all the product information like images, categories etc, but i'm struggling with the attributes, seem like they didn't populate properly?
They have been added to all of my products and are visable on product page but not in the attributes tab thus I cannot setup filters based on attributes:
missing attributes
but in fact they are populated
i need the attributes to be visable on attributes tab so i can setup filters
